# How to handle pop-ups in Jmeter automation tool?

Tags: unit-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0, window-tester

I am trying to perform load testing on particular application form of a portal using JMeter tool. I have recorded the whole scenario using blazemeter tool and exported it into .jmx file. In the JMeter tool, I have imported the file, able to login to the portal through JMeter, and parameterized the whole fields required to fill the application form.The problem is at last, request of all the data against those field is going but in the response I am getting "Data Failed", ultimately unable to submit the form through JMeter.This can be due to the pop-up which can not be recorded by blazemeter but it pops up at the time of submission on the actual portal, so **how to handle that pop up in JMeter to submit the form?**I am using apache-JMeter 5.2.1.I am also attaching the screenshots for reference. I am looking forward for help.[pop up shown on window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCU5s.png)[request data shown in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sANMT.png)[Pop-up shown on actual window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wt5YF.png)[Logged in successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4LaE.png)

Comment: Please provide a clear question also learn the basics of jmeter how it works jmeter doesn't interacts with the website UI elements instead it plays with the http request for your website where the backend is served

Comment: Please suggest me how to handle the confirmation pop-up(in javascript) using JMeter tool? Is there any other alternative to handle that pop-up?

Comment: Make manual form submission from the browser(say chrome) with chrome devtools-network tab open check what is the request happening in the backend you will get the data use this value to submit the form also this link will help you https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network

Answer (score 0):

Cross-check the request from the real browser and from JMeter using a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), the requests must be the same (apart from dynamic data which needs to be [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start))

If you're using parameterization - ensure that [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) have their anticipated values [using Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/)

Given you send the same request you should be getting the same response.

If you will not be able to figure out the cause yourself - consider adding [.har files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAR_(file_format)) for requests from the real browser and from JMeter to your question so we could take a look.

Answer (score 0):

link for the har file of real browser: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_zopIDpOjniqBsXtcDs53Zujzv62UxYt/view?usp=sharing][1]

link for .jmx file: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sZWeN3OfXxjvHlGn8bAjzGyP4Kq0TqwV/view?usp=sharing][1]

I am unable to handle confirmation pop-up (in javascript) through JMeter tool.